# How to get all the IP addresses of a client's tor circuit

Tags: python, tor, stem

Suppose I am sending a request to a .onion server (http://xxxxxx.onion/hello). Is there any way to find out the IP address of the 3 relies (guard/middle/exit node) of the client's circuit? I can check it using Tor Browser but I need to do it in python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the Stem project, which provides a Python API for the Tor client? https://stem.torproject.org/api.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have looked at it but can't understand how to get the IPs for a requests session. I will be really helpful if you can provide an example of how to do it. @AKX